# Karate API - Why response in not returning to called feature file

Tags: karate

I am calling login feature from another feature under background tag by passing un, pwd and endpoint url like below. Login feature is running successfully but the response of it is not returned to called feature file.

```
  @Add
  Feature: Adding products

  Background:

  * table loginDetails
  | username | password | endPointURL                      |
  | 'kUser' | 'kPass' | 'https://qa1.com/shop/login/login' |

  * def result = call read('Login.feature') loginDetails
  * print 'Result-'+response
  * print 'Result-'+result.response
  @loginTest
  Scenario: running @loginTest from runner file
  * print 'Login response -'+result.responseCookies
```

This is what i am getting in response.

```
   13:08:53.470 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
   "redirect": false,
  "loginSuccess": true,
  "redirectUrl": ""
  }

  13:08:53.519 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print]
  13:08:53.546 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] RUResult-undefined
  13:08:53.547 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Login response -undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a data table/ JSON array to the called feature you will get JSON array in return.

Here `result` object will have JSON array/list like data, so you have to read that variable accordingly

for the above example try,

```
* print result[0].response
* print result[0].responseCookies
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It worked for me.

Comment: perhaps while using karate.call its throwing polygot exception. any idea please
* if ( testData == "Yes") output = karate.call('file:features/commonFunctions.feature@party1') ({ 'companyId' : companyId  })
* print output.id